# Creating or killing a already created process in C

Tags: c, linux, process, fork, createprocess

I want to create a app that, when run with *-s* argument, creates a background process and kills it when run with *-q*. An example code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char opt = getopt(argc, argv, "sq");

    if(opt == 's'){
        if ( fork()==0 ){
            while(1); //Just something to make fork run forever
        }
    }
    else if (opt == 'q'){
        //Something to kill the fork
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, I am not sure how to kill that specific process. Does somebody know how to kill that specific fork(), or some other method of solving the issue?

Comment: You need to store the child pid in persistent storage (e.g. a file) so that it can be retrieved and killed the next time the program runs.

Comment: What should happen if you run the program N times with `-s` and then M times with `-q`?

Comment: If the program is run the second time with -s before killing the fork with -q, it should display an error message and not do anything else.